# Flutter app crashes on specific device (grey screen)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, debugging, dialog

So far my Flutter app turned out to work fine on Android and iOS in production(on different devices), but last week I got a complaint about the app crashing on an iPhone X. I tried to reproduce this bug on a iPhone X simulator but in debug mode it does not happen and there are no errors in the error logs. The crash happens after opening a dialog, so I think it's a layout error:

```html
void showDialogWithoutContext(String title, String message) {
    if (navigatorKey.currentContext != null) {
      showDialog(
          context: navigatorKey.currentContext as BuildContext,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => BlurryDialog(title, message));
    }
  }
```

Code of the BlurryDialog widget:

```html
class BlurryDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  String title;
  String content;

  BlurryDialog(this.title, this.content, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BlurryDialog> createState() => _BlurryDialogState();
}

class _BlurryDialogState extends State<BlurryDialog> {
  TextStyle textStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6),
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: Text(widget.title, style: textStyle),
          content: Text(widget.content, style: textStyle),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can reproduce the grey screen on a iPhone X simulator? Or does somebody see a problem in my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't look in details at your question but it sounds like a screen overflow issue. ask yourself, is the screen of the device getting the grey box smaller than the rest of the other devices that are not getting the error? There is another possibility which is local display configuration of the client device. some people will need bigger text to show on thier phone and this setting will affect how your application renders the display and can cause overflow in some instances.